# R: Count and convert to number

Tags: r, count

I have a dataframe with the following format.

```
A    B
xxx 100;2;30;5
yyy 30;5
zzz 35
```

How to count the number of numbers in column B in second column and convert to the count as follows:

```
A    B
xxx  4
yyy  2
zzz  1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming your data are in a `data.frame` named `Data`, a combination of `strsplit` and `sapply` make short work of this.

```
Data$C <- sapply(strsplit(Data$B, ";"), length)
```

`strsplit` is vectorized, so it splits each element of column `Data$B` by `";"` and returns a list of vectors.  The list has one element for each row in `Data` and each list element contains a vector (e.g. `"100;2;30;5"` is converted to `c("100","2","30","5")`).  The `sapply` call returns the length of each vector in the list.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
dfr$B<-nchar(as.character(dfr$B))-nchar(gsub(";","",dfr$B))+1
```

Edit: I think this should be slightly faster:

```
dfr$B<-nchar(as.character(dfr$B))-nchar(gsub(";","",dfr$B, fixed=TRUE))+1
```